# c# equivalent of fscanf()

Tags: c#, scanf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Looking for C# equivalent of scanf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472202/looking-for-c-sharp-equivalent-of-scanf)

I am trying to convert a line of code from c to c#

```
fscanf(fp, "%d %d\n", &x,&y);
```

is there an equivalent function for fscanf() in c#? how do i convert this line of code?

Update:
fp is a file pointer to a text file which contains an input like this

```
0 0
```

I need to save the integer inputs to x and y, respectively.

Comment: what is fp in this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var parts = streamReader.ReadLine().Split(new char[]{' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
int x = Int32.Parse(parts[0]);
int y = Int32.Parse(parts[1]);
```

Comment: Rather than only post a block of code, please *explain* why this code solves the problem posed. Without an explanation, this is not an answer.

Comment: @MartijnPieters This is my style. If you don't like the answer, simply don't upvote(as you do now). *A block of code?* 3 lines?

Comment: Your post ended up in the 'low quality posts' queue, and I elected to give feedback. Make whatever you want of that. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters It seems OP doesn't think the same :)

Answer (score -2):

```
String.Format("someFormatString", MyFileStreamReader.ReadLine());
```

Answer (score -2):

Check out the [BinaryReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.aspx) class.  In C# you would use a Stream object in place of the C FILE pointer.  Something like this should work

```
System.IO.Stream fp = System.IO.File.OpenRead(@"C:\Path\To\My\File.txt");
double x, y;
using (var reader = new System.IO.BinaryReader(fp))
{
    x = reader.ReadDouble();
    y = reader.ReadDouble();
}
```

Comment: No, something like that will not work. It's for reading floats stored in 4 bytes, in binary, not in a human readable string.