# Reading values from console

Tags: c#

I want to know if there are something like C’s `scanf()` or `printf()` in C#?

```
String [] a1; 
String a = Console.ReadLine();
a1= s.split(); 

Int []  b; 

for(...) {b[i] = Int32.Parse(a1[i])}...
```

I could do something like `scanf("%d %d %d %d %d", &a, ..., &e);`?

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have here? It looks like it works.

Comment: For `printf` there is `String.Format`.

Comment: I know it works, but i wanna know if there are something "more easy" to reading my x integer numbers...?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Looking for C# equivalent of scanf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/472202/looking-for-c-sharp-equivalent-of-scanf)

Comment: Sure. `int[] readXIntegers(int x){ int [] data = new int[x]; var arr = Console.ReadLine().Split(new char[]{ ' ' }); for(int i = 0; i < x; i++){ data[i] = Int32.Parse(arr[i]); } return data; }`

Answer (score 2):

The closest thing C# has to `printf` is [`Console.WriteLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.writeline.aspx) (or [`String.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1csw23d.aspx) to output to a string).  The syntax is different but the concept is the same.  e.g. `printf("%4.2f",100)` becomes `Console.WriteLine("{0:0.00}",100);`

There is no equivalent to `scanf`.  You need to use `Console.ReadLine` and parse the string manually.

Answer (score 1):

After some looking around, It seems like c# does not have an implementation of `scanf`.

You can, however, use [regular expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228595%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to do the same thing

it does, however, have an equivelant of `printf` in the form of [String.Format()](http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-format)

```
int i = 5;
double d = 5.0;
String.Format("this is an int:{0}, this is a double:{1}", i, d);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  [DllImport("msvcrt.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention =  CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
  public static extern int scanf(string buffer, string format, ref int arg0, ref int arg1);
```

That will let you use scanf in C#, i think:)

If not, you have to use split and convert:)

Comment: Please don't suggest (don't even think about) this.

Comment: I was trying to be nice only, why so serious?

Comment: I'll give you a +1, made me laugh!