# How to convert sscanf function call to C#?

Tags: c#, c++, c, icu

I have this fun sscanf function call I need to convert to C#:

```
u_sscanf(tag.c_str(), "%*[<]%[^<>=:!]%[<>=:!]%[-.MAXIN0-9]%*[>]", tkey, top, txval)
```

How would I best go about this? Are there any libraries that can help me?

Comment: There are two ways you can challenge this monster without any library. You do not want to hear both probably as one is "manual parsing" (as some help: translate the above to some `Regex` and just pass whatever `Console.ReadLine()` passes to you) and the second one involves `DllImport` and a little bit of unsafe code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Looking for C# equivalent of scanf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472202/looking-for-c-sharp-equivalent-of-scanf)

Comment: @X39 that's what I was thinking as well. pinvoking is not an option though.